# Determine unused jars by code coverage?

Tags: java, jar, code-coverage

I have a project with a million jars (well, a lot). They came to me by maven, and I only use a small set of functionality. For cleanness sake, I was wondering with jars I could do without.

My first thought was to run the program with a code-coverage tool, and then find the classes that are touched.

Has anyone done this before? Or are there smarter tricks to achieve the same?

Comment: remove the jars from the classpath one by one re-add the last on e removed when the build breaks

Comment: @ratchet freak - Bad idea, won't detect indirect runtime dependencies unless the build includes complete integration testing.

Comment: @ratchet freak - That could work, but that is my brute force last restort.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run the project using the `-verbose:class` VM option. This will print for all loaded classes where they are loaded from. Using some smart parsing app/grep/regexp will allow you to filter the jar names into a set of unique entries and tell you which are used.

I think this would be easier because it will automatically tell you if a class is used and if so in which jar.

Of course the problem with this and code coverage is that it will be possible that you delete a jar that is only used in some exceptional case, but your compiler will complain if you deleted one or two too many, leaving you with the (mostly not too complicated) task of finding which jar the class is in.

Possible suggestion when using linux:

`java -verbose:class   <your startup command here> | grep "\[Loaded" | grep -o "from .*\]" | cut -c 6- | sort | uniq`

If you aren't using linux, then save to a file, get a linux machine and run on linux (or use something to run bash commands on windows)

Comment: Thanks, this is probably the easiest way to go. I wonder, as propably more people will have this question, if anyone already has some code to do this.. It is a nice excercise, but why reinvent the wheel..

Comment: @RobAu Added an example for linux. Not ideal, but does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using a tool that already exists, like [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/) or [JDepend](http://clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html).

As with all static analysis tools, the use of reflection or DI frameworks can throw this off; I've resorted to custom tools that use this and other inputs to figure things out, although it's still static.

For full runtime usage info you can use Thirler's solution, although whether or not it's complete may depend on which code paths are followed.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Maven Dependency Plugin` for analysing your dependency tree. It will also suggest you the dependecies which are downloaded/added to your project because they are dependent to any other jars.

Do run a `mvn dependency:tree` and see if you are using few unrequired jars.

Comment: That won't work, as I need the dynamic behaviour, not a static analysis.